# VS Code not starting on WSL

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, vscode-remote

Yesterday when I tried to open my VS Code then WSL started updating after the update, I started getting errors and after that, I am not able to start VS Code.

`Errors`

/mnt/c/Users/dell/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl-0.72.0/scripts/wslCode.sh: 50: /home/rahulrajput83/.vscode-server-server/bin/d045a5eda657f4d7b676dedbfa7aab8207f8a075/bin/code: not found

[image: Errors]

`What I have tried`
I have searched for the error on google and found some solutions here https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/6294

I have tried the solutions available on above link but problem is not fixed.

I have used these commands `sudo apt update`  `wsl.exe --shutdown`

Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: `wsl.exe --shutdown` needs running from cmd or powershell. Then do `wsl --update`, restart wsl, run `sudo apt update -y && sudo apt upgrade -y && sudo apt autoremove -y` to make sure it's all updated, then try running `code .` from within your project dir in WSL. It should update the WSL installation of VScode for you if needed.

Comment: @michjnich I have tried your commands but getting the same error yet.